# Reading words from UTF8 textfile to count letters, it counts everything right except the very first word

Tags: php, html, text-files

**Here's my UTF-8 text file:**

> orange[*t:주황색*][*r:juhwangsaeg]
>
> apple[*t:사과*][*r:sagwa]

**I break it up into an array:**

`$word`: orange,apple

`$trans`: 주황색,사과

`$readable`: r:juhwangsaeg, sagwa

I only need to count the letters of each `$word`, so for the first word "orange":

```
$len = iconv_strlen($word, "UTF-8"); //$word=orange

print "word=$word,len=$len"; // $word=orange,$len=7
```

The problem is that `$len` always gives me 7 instead of 6 when it counts "orange", but it has no problem reading the next word (word=apple, len=5) or any other words in my array.

I've tried several different ways to overcome this problem using `mb_strlen` etc, but I still can't figure out why it keeps counting an extra character when I read the first word.

Comment: your counting the comma as well

Comment: The commas are not included. I'm just reading one word from an array which gets assigned to $word to check it's string length.

Comment: Try to apply trim() before counting length.

Comment: Tried that, it's not working.  I'm stump to understand why I only get the error with the first word but not the rest.  There must be something preceding this word but there is nothing.  It prints out "orange" as expected, but not the correct count of letters.

Comment: What does `var_dump($word, bin2hex($word));` show?

Comment: Check if your textfile has a BOM.

Comment: OK I have solved the problem.  Using CBroe's advice, I ran the following code:     

$str = file_get_contents('textfile');
$bom = pack("CCC", 0xef, 0xbb, 0xbf);
if (0 === strncmp($str, $bom, 3)) {
    echo "BOM detected - file is UTF-8\n";

To detect if BOM exist in the file, it does!
Then I used the following code to remove UTF8 BOM:

$bom = pack('H*','EFBBBF');
$text = preg_replace("/^$bom/", '', $text);

I also found another solution to fix this problem to remove special characters:

$words = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $words);

Comment: Álvaro González  - I ran the code you gave me and it gave me the following for the word 'orange':

string(9) "-----e" string(18) "efbbbf2d2d2d2d2d65"

Comment: `efbbbf2d2d2d2d2d65`? That can't be your variable. Word `orange`, when encoded in UTF-8, is expected to have these 6 bytes: `6f 72 61 6e 67 65`. Apart from a leading BOM, you have a lot of consecutive literal `-`... :-?

Comment: My apologies, I ran that code after a gapfill function that I use to strip certain characters (orange -> o----e) and I used the gapfill result by mistake.  Here's the result prior to running my gapfill function:
string(9) "orange"
string(18) "efbbbf6f72616e6765"

Here's the result for the next word:
var dump = string(5) "apple"
string(10) "6170706c65"

I'm also not sure why there are consecutive literals before "orange" as I was not familiar with BOM in the first place, but the code I submitted seem to solve this problem.